# MySQL server has gone away when importing WordPress sql file

Tags: mysql

I downloaded **live Wordpress** website to my local machine to work on it over my local environment. Since **database file** is missing, the webpage was not the same as it was on production. So I exported, **dumped** the sql file using **SSH** , and now I try to **import** it to my local **XAMPP** envinornent with my **Mac Terminal** using the command **below**:

```
mysql -h127.0.0.1 -u root -p wp_database < ../../wp.sql;
```

*And Terminal throws this **error***:

> ERROR 2006 (HY000) at line 899: MySQL server has gone away

What could be the reason for this problem?

What I've done to solve the problem:

**1)** I've upgraded max_allowed_packet to 128MB

**2)** I've upgraded innodb_lock_wait_timeout = 60000

**3)** I've upgraded innodb_log_file_size = 128M

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After setting `max_allowed_packet` did you restarted server?

Try passing directly to client. Once i faced this issue and global update and the `my.cnf` settings didn't work for me but this worked.

```
mysql -h127.0.0.1 -u root -p --max_allowed_packet=1073741824 wp_database < ../../wp.sql;
```

Comment: Yes, I restarted the server and I've also use the approach you mentioned. That was the way I exported the sql file but it doesn't work on my local machine. I updated the error message. Could you please check?

Comment: Could it be, due to an syntax error or smth inside the sql file? BEacuse it says line 899

Comment: Line 899 have a large execution query which crosses upper limit on the size of any single message between the MySQL server and clients

Comment: There is an insert query at line 899.

Comment: Is there a way I can increase this size?

Comment: Increase max_allowed_packet=1073741824;

Comment: Try running this query *Set global max_allowed_packet=64*1024*1024;*

Comment: It worked! But the thing that  I don't understand is why it wasn't working even tho I updated my.cnf and passed the max_allowed_packet=1073741824 inside the query itself

Comment: great to know that.

Answer (score 1):

Try the below code

mysql -h127.0.0.1 -u root -p --max_allowed_packet=1073741824 wp_database < ../../wp.sql --verbose --force --wait --reconnect

Comment: I tried your approach It looked like something was  going on. I mean there were bunch of errors and creation things but at last I checked my webpage. 

There are still missing tables

Comment: While executing it will return the verbose like warnings on the query  etc, can you able to check the logs ...

have a look at https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/mysqlimport.html#option_mysqlimport_verbose